# I can't make cumulative_filtering work

Tags: datatables-1.10, yadcf

I am using yadcf 0.8.8 and DataTables 1.10.10 with Select2 3.5.3.  My data source is from AJAX but I am not using server side processing.  I could not make the cumulative_filtering work.  It looks very straight forward, but clearly something is not right.  Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

```
yadcf.init(oTable, 
    [
        {
            column_number: 0,
            filter_default_label: "...",
            filter_type: "multi_select",
            select_type: 'select2',
            filter_reset_button_text: false
        }, {
            column_number: 1,
            filter_default_label: "...",
            filter_type: "multi_select",
            select_type: 'select2',
            sort_as: 'none',
            filter_match_mode: 'exact',
            filter_reset_button_text: false
        }, {
            column_number: 2,
            filter_default_label: "...",
            filter_type: "multi_select",
            select_type: 'select2',
            filter_reset_button_text: false
        }, {
            column_number: 3,
            filter_default_label: "...",
            filter_type: "multi_select",
            select_type: 'select2',
            filter_reset_button_text: false
        }, {
            column_number: 4,
            filter_default_label: "...",
            filter_type: "multi_select",
            select_type: 'select2',
            filter_reset_button_text: false
        }, {
            column_number: 5,
            filter_default_label: "...",
            filter_type: "multi_select",
            select_type: 'select2',
            filter_reset_button_text: false
        }, {
            column_number: 6,
            filter_default_label: "...",
            filter_type: "multi_select",
            select_type: 'select2',
            filter_reset_button_text: false
        }, {
            column_number: 7,
            filter_default_label: "...",
            filter_reset_button_text: false
        }, {
            column_number: 8,
            filter_type: "range_number_slider",
            filter_delay: 400,
            filter_reset_button_text: false
        }, {
            column_number: 9,
            filter_type: "range_number_slider",
            filter_delay: 400,
            filter_reset_button_text: false
        }, {
            column_number: 10,
            filter_type: "range_number_slider",
            filter_delay: 400,
            filter_reset_button_text: false
            //SalesPrice
        }, {
            column_number: 11,
            filter_default_label: "...",
            filter_type: "multi_select",
            select_type: 'select2',
            filter_reset_button_text: false
        }, {
            column_number: 12,
            filter_default_label: "...",
            filter_type: "text",
            filter_delay: 400,
            case_insensitive: true,
            filter_reset_button_text: false
        }
    ],
    {
        cumulative_filtering: true
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to upgrade your yadcf library to the [lastest version](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/master/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js) because that feature was added in yadcf 0.8.9.beta.13 ,see [relevant comment](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/issues/196#issuecomment-133191160)

Comment: It works! Great!  Thank you.  Although cumulative_filtering: true did not remove the individual reset buttons on my table, I put them back which is not a problem at all.

Comment: We needed a cumulative filtering solution for some time but now I realize it is killing the multiple selection aspect as the table is filtered with the first value selected.  Do you think it is possible to either show the filtered out options still in the selection list under a seperator or faded?  Or at least with the first selection to have the other options still available...  Otherwise I will try to make the cumulative_filtering option selectable by user.

Comment: My bad , the `externally_triggered: true` removed the reset buttons, as to the "show the filtered out as disabled options" open an issue and I will consider it later on...

Comment: I think the issue is not to be able to see the disabled ones but when we select one option for a column the other options for that column disappear.  It makes multiple selection not compatible with cumulative_filtering.  I understand why it is happening but I think one should be able to select multiple options and see what the other columns are left with. I will try to open an issue for this.  It's going to be my first time.